# Rails session variable is not saving

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view i have remote linkaction, which set session variable:

```
%ul
              %li
                = link_to "Ростов-на-Дону", set_city_path(city_id: 1), remote: true, class: "city-selector-list-city"
              %li
                = link_to "Ставрополь", set_city_path(city_id: 2), remote: true, class: "city-selector-list-city"
              %li
                = link_to "Краснодар", set_city_path(city_id: 3), remote: true, class: "city-selector-list-city"
```

and method:

```
def set_city_session
    #binding.pry
    if [1, 2, 3].include? params[:city_id].to_i
      session[:city_id] = params[:city_id].to_i
      if session[:city_id] == 1
        @city_id = "Ростов-на-Дону"
      end
      if session[:city_id] == 2
        @city_id = "Ставрополь"
      end
      if session[:city_id] == 3
        @city_id = "Краснодар"
      end
    end
    #binding.pry
  end
```

view:

```
$("#city-name-link").text("#{escape_javascript(@city_id)}");
window.location.reload();
```

but when i click on other link or go on some other page i see, that my session is "deleted",   value is not stored, for example if i set = 3, i see that it is = 1. But why? How to store value in session?

upd:

layout:

```
- if session[:city_id] == 1
                  Ростов-на-Дону
                - if session[:city_id] == 2
                  Ставрополь
                - if session[:city_id] == 3
                  Краснодар
```

Comment: you are just assigning citi_id to session[:city_id](write operation), you are not using session[:city_id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a value in a session, you have to set the value in the session itself. Currently, you're setting instance variables, which will get lost if you're reloading the page:

A better way to do it will be to either set the session variables directly, or not reloading the Window on ajax success:

```
def set_city_session
    #binding.pry
    if [1, 2, 3].include? params[:city_id].to_i
      session[:city_id] = params[:city_id].to_i
      if session[:city_id] == 1
        session[:city_name] = "Ростов-на-Дону"
      end
      if session[:city_id] == 2
        session[:city_name] = "Ставрополь"
      end
      if session[:city_id] == 3
        session[:city_name] = "Краснодар"
      end
    end
    #binding.pry
end
$("#city-name-link").text("#{escape_javascript(session[:city_name])}");
```

If you'd like to set a "default" value for the sessions, you'd be best doing something like this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_session


    private

    def set_session
        session[:city_id]   ||= "1"
        session[:city_name] ||= "Ростов-на-Дону"
    end
end
```

Comment: session[:city_id] = params[:city_id].to_i  !!! i set it here! than i use it in layout: `- if session[:city_id] == 1
                  Ростов-на-Дону
                - if session[:city_id] == 2
                  Ставрополь
                - if session[:city_id] == 3
                  Краснодар`

Comment: Yep but what about your instance variables? If you reload your window, your instance variable will go.

Comment: also how when user come to my website set as default session[:city_id] = 1 and session[:city_name] = "Ростов-на-Дону" ?

Comment: You can use the `||=` function with a `before_action` filter -- would you like me to write some code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `set_city_session` method doesn't return anything so I think you're running into a `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error when you click on your links, and that prevents the session variable from getting set. Check your JS console for the HTML response and you'll probably see it there too.

If you really don't need to return anything (even a success/error flag), you can add this to your `set_city_session` method and it will work:

`render :nothing => true`

Comment: i must render js set_city_session